# count distinct values over columns

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I struggle to get the result for

here is my dataset

| A | B | C | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 5 | 5 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |

result expected

| A | B | C | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

PG 9.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A correlated subquery against a `VALUES` table should do the trick:**

```sql
SELECT
    t.A, t.B, t.C,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v.n) FROM (VALUES(t.A),(t.B),(t.C)) AS v(n)) AS cnt
FROM table t
```

If you wanted separate calculations on the values such as both counting and summing, you could use a lateral join (a.k.a `APPLY`) over `VALUES` instead:

```sql
SELECT A, B, C ,D, E, v.countDistinct, v.countNotNull, v.Total
FROM  test,
LATERAL (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v.n), COUNT(v.n), SUM(v.n)
    FROM (VALUES (A),(B),(C), (D), (E)) AS v(n)
) AS v(countDistinct, countNotNull, Total)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested CASE WHEN structure

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (
>   "A" INTEGER,
>   "B" INTEGER,
>   "C" INTEGER,
>   "cnt" INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO test
>   ("A", "B", "C", "cnt")
> VALUES
>   ('2', '1', '2', '0'),
>   ('1', '5', '5', '0'),
>   ('2', '1', '4', '0'),
>   ('1', '1', '1', '0');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE test
> SET cnt = 
> CASE  WHEN "A" = "B" THEN
>          CASE
>              WHEN "A" = "C" THEN 1
>              ELSE
>               2
>          END
>     ELSE
>           CASE
>              WHEN "A" = "C" THEN 2
>              WHEN "B" = "C" THEN 2
>              ELSE
>               3
>          END
>      END
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test
> ```
>
> ```
>  A |  B |  C | cnt
> -: | -: | -: | --:
>  2 |  1 |  2 |   2
>  1 |  5 |  5 |   2
>  2 |  1 |  4 |   3
>  1 |  1 |  1 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=140199a73122b1dde70aa90f509b4444)*

Comment: Why are you inserting integers as strings?

Comment: the tools i used makes this, and Postgres doesn't mind, so i let it stand.